# Prevent solution explorer from hiding when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I debug in Visual Studio the Solution Explorer is closed.

How do I make it stay open?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you open the Solution Explorer during a debugging session, it should get saved as a preference when you close Visual Studio, making sure that it gets opened the next time you debug.

Answer (score 19):

When debugging go to View -> Solution Explorer to see the solution explorer.  As long as you don't close it, it should show up wherever you leave it the next time you are debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Go to TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings
.Reset all the change setting